# Turning 2D array into a .png file (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, image, file-io, multidimensional-array, png

I am creating a pixel art drawing tool in JavaScript.

Pretty simple: select the colour on the left side, and apply it to the square in the 2D-array on the right that you click on. I would like to know how/if you can take the colour co-ordinates and output them as pixels in a .png file? (or other type of image file)